# 350w power supply enough?

Tags: power-supply, bsod

I am working on a malfunctioning windows 10 pc for a friend of mine.

It's a prebuild system with a gtx 1650, 8gb ddr4, 1 nvme ssd, 1 hdd and a Ryzen 3 3200G.

According to my friend it has been having random bluescreens for as long as he's had it. Event viewer shows kernel power 41 error, I have done pretty much every scan and repair for corrupted windows files.

Is it possible the power supply (corsair VS350) is just not enough for this system?

I have not been able to recreate a bluescreen so far using stress tests, no thermal issues either. Just trying to rule out possible problems.

Comment: First I'd test the computer with Linux, that would help to decide whether the issue is software or hardware related.

Comment: It could be the powersupply. Keep in mind, the PSU is responsible for everything power related. That includes obviously providing power to the CPU and GPU, but it also is responsible for providing power to the USB ports. If lots of USB ports are connected, for example an external Harddisk, it may be just enough to create a peak the PSU can't handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say it for sure, but PSU may be the source of a problem. You use 11,4A on +3,3V line while PSU has 14A available*. There is still reserve, but thin enough that some small non-compliance of elements may be a problem. Especially that this Corsair doesn't have 80 Plus certification.

Anyway, start with diagnostic on another system. Use Linux LiveCD or Hiren's BootCD and start CPU and GPU stress tests simultaneously.
If it crash in such situation - supply is too weak. If not - you have another problem.

*Sources:

- https://outervision.com/b/wgIL4X
- https://www.conrad.com/p/corsair-vs350-pc-power-supply-unit-350-w-no-certification-1487355#!

Comment: yeah i figured it was close to the PSU limit, thank you I will try and see if any linux benchmarks crash